# wrapInner() with href of children elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have next structure - there are 7 blocks:

```
<div class="blog-item">
   <h2>...</h2>
   <p>...</p>
   <div class="jcomments-links">
      <a class="readmore-link" href="..."></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to receive href of the inner link, delete its parent block with link and add a link inside block with class="blog-item" with the same href as deleted link...
I had wrote this:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".blog-item a.readmore-link").each(function() {
        var ahref = jQuery(this).attr("href");
        jQuery(this).parent('.jcomments-links').remove();
        jQuery(this).parent().closest('.blog-item').wrapInner(function () {
           return "<a href='" + ahref + "'></a>"
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

But something wrong. There will not appear new link. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hello, you try:  wrapInner( $(" <a href=' " + ahref + " '></a>") );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (run the snippet to see it work, and you'll have to use the inspector to see that the html is correct):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".blog-item a.readmore-link").each(function () {
        var ahref = $(this).attr("href"),
            $wrapItem = $(this).closest('.blog-item');

        $(this).closest('.jcomments-links').remove();
        $wrapItem.wrapInner('<a href="' + ahref + '"/>');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blog-item">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
    <div class="jcomments-links">
        remove 
        <a class="readmore-link" href="http://www.example.com">example</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

its because you are deleting `$(this)` when you remove the `.parent('.jcomments-links')` from the DOM, so the reference to add the `<a>` to the `.blog-item` has not reference when you say `$(this).closest()` cause there is no more `$(this)`.

try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".blog-item a.readmore-link").each(function () {
        var ahref = $(this).attr("href");
        $(this).closest('.blog-item').append("<a href='" + ahref + "'>This is my new link</a");
        $(this).parent('.jcomments-links').remove();        
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blog-item">
    <h2>...</h2>
    <p>...</p>
    <div class="jcomments-links">
        <a class="readmore-link" href="this-is-my-href-i-want">This is the Link woo woo</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ten's variant is working. This just add another link, not wrap inner part of block.